# 2 icons when migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have just migrated to Android Studio from Eclipse.

Everything is working fine, just one thing, it is installing me 2 icons with the same pic.

I don't really know what is going on, as it is my first day with Gradle.

What I can say is I have one library : ProgressWheel

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

And 2 Gradle files for the same project, kind of weird:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

And another for the same project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.spmkt.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':progressWheel')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
}
```

What should I do?

Tx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!
in the lib ProgressWheel, I edit AndroidManifest.xml and remove entry point :

```
            <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then it worked well!